# NodeJS [].forEach undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I have strange problem with `[].forEach` in NodeJS.

(Using NodeJs v5.4.1)

Have this code in a function

```
function _buildUserQuestionsForDisplay(question,callback){
    var res = {}
    ["is_open","created","deleted","_id"].forEach(function(v){
        res[v] = question[v]
    })
   ...
   ...
}
```

Throwing an error:

> ["is_open","created","deleted","_id"].forEach(function(v){
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

It works if I'm changing the code to

```
var arr = ["is_open","created","deleted","_id"];
arr.forEach(function(v){
    res[v] = question[v]
})
```

I've tested the same function on `Chrome.console` and the first way works.
I know that both using `V8` JS engine, is it a bug or something I'm missing with Javascript rules?

thanks!

Comment: Does Node also fail with a standalone minimal version of that code? Are you using any modules that may be changing `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype`?

Comment: If you put a semi-colon after `var res = {}` does it work then?

Comment: @Andy you we're right,I feel kinda stupid, Javascript compiler should forgive about that if I put newline, no?

Comment: @robertklep well, it's a fact, adding a semicolon did solve it.

btw using VisualStudio for mac(awesome!), maybe something with newLine characters over there

Comment: @DanielKrom I removed my comment because Node does fail without a semi-colon, which was rather unexpected to me (and invalidated my comment =)

Comment: @robertklep it's ok, I was unexpected either that it make issues

Comment: @robertklep, [it breaks here too](https://jsfiddle.net/34fco4gh/)

Comment: I guess that the reason for this is buried somewhere in the [Automatic Semicolon Insertion rules](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9).

Comment: @robertklep i guess `{a:1}["b"] //undefined` was kinda what I was doing, this semicolons are important sometimes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code breaks if you don't have a semi-colon after this line:

```
var res = {}
```

To minimise these problems a good idea is to use a linter if you're not using one. Both [`JSHint`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwj4o9us9cfMAhUJCBoKHYInDBQQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjshint.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHqeBOMvhdKFMrzGff7heKdyCHSgA&bvm=bv.121421273,d.d2s) and [`ESLint`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiP2uag9cfMAhXMfxoKHXABCoUQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Feslint.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNETkIcsqHgsrPDzatCqKZiSd_HKIw) can be added as dev plugins to your code editor (I use ESLint with the Airbnb stylesheet in SubmlimeText), and can also be added to your workflow using Gulp or Grunt to catch these kind of errors before you commit code.

> If you choose to omit semicolons where possible, my advice is to insert them immediately before the opening parenthesis or square bracket in any statement that begins with one of those tokens, or any which begins with one of the arithmetic operator tokens "/", "+", or "-" if you should happen to write such a statement. - [blog entry by Michaeljohn Clement 2010](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons)

Comment: Thanks! btw I'm using Visual Studio for mac editor (Great NodeJS editor for mac, better than 9000% CPU NetBeans) but maybe Microsoft did something wrong with new line character that the compiler won't like

Comment: I think that "some reason" is that what the code is doing without the semicolon is trying to access the "_id" property of the empty object, which is of course undefined and doesn't have a forEach()  method.

Comment: @nnnnnn As I understood; my code was doing the next thing (for example)

`{a:5}["a"] //5` and `{a:5}["b"] //undefined`, and on that I was doing forEach, which is exactly what you described for `_id` key

Comment: Yep, this has nothing to do with wrong new line characters or Node as an environment specifically. On the contrary: this is the intended behavior of ASI in JS. `var res = {}[ indexer ].forEach(...)` is grammatically valid expression and thus no semicolon is inserted to break that.